# apache2 rewrite rules issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok here is what I got..

If I use http://192.168.1.209/restAPI/player/read it fails with error "The requested URL /restAPI/player/read was not found on this server."

```
[Thu Dec 14 16:24:54.572442 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 960] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 192.168.1.33:56408] 192.168.1.33 - - 
[192.168.1.209/sid#7f089b61b808][rid#7f089b5390a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/restAPI/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/restAPI/player/read.php -> player/read.php
[Thu Dec 14 16:24:54.572490 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 960] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 192.168.1.33:56408] 192.168.1.33 - - 
[192.168.1.209/sid#7f089b61b808][rid#7f089b5390a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/restAPI/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'player/read.php'
[Thu Dec 14 16:24:54.572503 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 960] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 192.168.1.33:56408] 192.168.1.33 - - 
[192.168.1.209/sid#7f089b61b808][rid#7f089b5390a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/restAPI/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/restAPI/player/read.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[Thu Dec 14 16:24:54.572508 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 960] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 192.168.1.33:56408] 192.168.1.33 - - 
[192.168.1.209/sid#7f089b61b808][rid#7f089b5390a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/restAPI/] pass through /var/www/html/restAPI/player/read.php
```

If I use http://192.168.1.209/restAPI/index.php/player/read it works
Below is relevant log

```
info postfix: /var/www/html/restAPI/index.php -> /var/www/html/restAPI/index.php/player/read
[Thu Dec 14 16:27:29.872076 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 963] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 192.168.1.33:56440] 192.168.1.33 - - 
[192.168.1.209/sid#7f089b61b808][rid#7f089b54f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/restAPI/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/restAPI/index.php/player/read -> index.php/player/read
[Thu Dec 14 16:27:29.872087 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 963] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 192.168.1.33:56440] 192.168.1.33 - - 
[192.168.1.209/sid#7f089b61b808][rid#7f089b54f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/restAPI/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php/player/read'
[Thu Dec 14 16:27:29.872102 2017] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 963] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 192.168.1.33:56440] 192.168.1.33 - - 
[192.168.1.209/sid#7f089b61b808][rid#7f089b54f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/restAPI/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/restAPI/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
[Thu Dec 14 16:27:29.872108 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 963] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 192.168.1.33:56440] 192.168.1.33 - - 
[192.168.1.209/sid#7f089b61b808][rid#7f089b54f0a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/restAPI/] pass through /var/www/html/restAPI/index.php
```

to make it more interesting, my actual file the function would call is /player/read.php
Also if I call http://192.168.1.209/restAPI/player/update which has no file in the /player dir it works
Here is my httaccess file content in the /restAPI dir

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You may want to investigate what part of your Apache configuration that add `.php` suffix (i.e your request  `/player/read` become `/player/read.php`).

Comment: where could that be ? i checked and i have only one .htaccess which is in my /var/www/html/restAPI which translates to http://192.168.1.209/restAPI
FYI my Apache built is
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-18T15:09:02

Comment: did you set `AllowOverride FileInfo Options`?

Comment: In the apache2.conf ?

Comment: found the problem, i created an entry in apache2.conf to allow AllowOverride FileInfo and that did the trick. Now it works as desired